# Reducing png file size in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to reduce the size of the png file in AS3

I used mLoader to load the png file and got the png's bitmap

```
public function savePng(bitmap:Bitmap,scale:Number):void
{
  var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bitmap.width*scale,bitmap.height*scale);
  bitmapData.drawWithQuality(mLoader,new Matrix(scale,0,0,scale), null, null, null , true, StageQuality.BEST);
  var pngEncorder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
  var bytes:ByteArray = pngEncorder.encode(bitmapData);
}
```

But when I saved the image,it appeared jagged.
I also used nid.image.encoder.PNGEncoder and PNGEncoder2,they were all useless.

Comment: Well yeah, of course things are gonna get jaggy when you scale the image. Use 9-tile scaling or something.

Comment: Does **reduce size** mean make less file bytes or make width & height smaller? If you want more compression without changing width/height then try JPEG compression. Anyways If jagged then try `.smoothing = true` before drawing container (where you `addChild` the bitmap). Also try **[bicubic interpolation](http://www.yoambulante.com/swf/labs/imageresize.swf)** like in Photoshop, example **[source](http://www.yoambulante.com/en/downloads/?getfile=imageresize)** to study as taken from **[this article](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/1042/1/The-word-is-interpolation/Page1.html)**.